# ParameterMixtureDistribution with custom distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I am trying to use `ParameterMixtureDistribution` with a custom distribution as the first argument. It does not evaluate. In attempting to solve my problem, I reverted to a much simpler scenario (below), which I am puzzled I cannot get to work. My assumption is that I am missing something terribly obvious.

If I do

```
ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  NormalDistribution[m, s], 
  m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m2, s2]
]
```

I get

```
NormalDistribution[m2, Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2]]
```

However, if I try and use a self-defined function as the first parameter, here just a Gaussian, it fails to evaluate.

First define a Gaussian:

```
f = 1/(s Sqrt[2 Pi]) Exp[-((x - m)^2/(2 s^2))]
```

Now try the same mixture:

```
ParameterMixtureDistribution[
  f, 
  m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m2, s2]
]
```

and it does not evaluate. Which is puzzling as I thought the two would be equivalent.

I have been playing around with a few things, none of which seem to work.

- Make `f` a `ProbabilityDistribution`
- Make `f` a `PDF`
- Add `Assumptions` to `ParameterMixtureDistribution`

I am starting to think I am just missing something very obvious. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

dist = ParameterMixtureDistribution[NormalDistribution[m, s], 
  m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m2, s2]]

(* NormalDistribution[m2, Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2]] *)
```

For comparison purposes,

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 stats = #[dist] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation, PDF[#, x] &, CDF[#, x] &}]

(* {0.000525, {m2, Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2], E^(-((-m2 + x)^2/(2 (s^2 + s2^2))))/(
  Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2]), 
  1/2 Erfc[(m2 - x)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2])]}} *)
```

For a user-defined function,

```
f = 1/(s Sqrt[2 π]) Exp[-((x - m)^2/(2 s^2))];
```

For Mathematica to consider `f` as a distribution you must use [`ProbabilityDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProbabilityDistribution.html)

```
fdist = ProbabilityDistribution[f, {x, -Infinity, Infinity},
   Assumptions -> m ∈ Reals && s > 0];

dist2 = ParameterMixtureDistribution[fdist, 
  m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m2, s2]]

(* ParameterMixtureDistribution[
 ProbabilityDistribution[E^(-((\[FormalX] - m)^2/(2 s^2)))/(
  Sqrt[2 π] s), {\[FormalX], -∞, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> m ∈ Reals && s > 0], m \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[m2, s2]] *)
```

While Mathematica does not recognize nor provide a concise notation, `dist2` is a valid distribution and produces the same results (albeit **extremely** slowly).

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 stats2 = #[dist2] & /@ {Mean, StandardDeviation, PDF[#, x] &, CDF[#, x] &}]

(* {58.3517, {m2, Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2], E^(-((m2 - x)^2/(2 (s^2 + s2^2))))/(
  Sqrt[2 π] Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2]), 
  1/2 Erfc[(m2 - x)/(Sqrt[2] Sqrt[s^2 + s2^2])]}} *)

Thread[stats == stats2] // Simplify

(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, that's great.